# Return random string from a list of strings? Field Calculator, Python

Tags: python, field-calculator, random, iteration

I am having an issue with producing the correct syntax to place random strings from a list of min into fields with the field calculator.

I have tried the following code:

```
import random

ran = ['kid', 'many', 'love', 'play']

random.shuffle(ran)

for i in ran:

print i
```

I am only getting one value? I would like to have a random values throughout the entire field.

Comment: Although you mention the Field Calculator you have not shown how that is needed to demonstrate what you are asking about. Consequently, this looks like a pure Python question that would be better researched or asked (without reference to the Field Calculator) at [so].

Comment: My apologies, I would like to place the strings kid, many, love, play into the fields randomly from the first Field down to the last field.

Comment: how do you do this in a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through everything in your list and only outputting the last value after the shuffle.  What you need to do is shuffle it for every field, and return a single record from the list for each row.

Try the following - in the field calculator select Python Parser, click on Show Codeblock, and enter this in the Pre-logic Script Code box:

```py
import random
def list_random(ran):
    random.shuffle(ran)
    return ran[0]
```

And in the expression, call the function and pass your list:

```py
list_random(['kid', 'many', 'love', 'play'])
```

This will random shuffle the list for each row, and pass the first value in the shuffled list each time.

[image]

[image]

---

Alternatively, instead of shuffling your list, you could select a random list index position for each row:

Pre-logic:

```py
import random
def list_random(ran):
    return ran[random.randint(0,len(ran)-1)]
```

Expression:

```py
list_random(['kid', 'many', 'love', 'play'])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by saying getting one value?
When I tested your script, it print shuffled elements from the list. like

```
import random

ran = ['kid', 'many', 'love', 'play']    
random.shuffle(ran)    
for i in ran:    
  print i

love
many
play
kid
```

Comment: My apologies, I would like to place the strings kid, many, love, play into the fields randomly from the first Field down to the last field.